# SEO issue with orphan pages and dynamic content

Tags: seo, react-js

On my page I have a blog page with pagination (arrows for navigation). Upon clicking on these arrows, new blog posts are dynamically rendered on the same page. Because of this functionality, any blog posts that aren't on the first page are considered orphan pages. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

- Implement proper pagination where clicking these buttons loads a new page on a new URL.
- Add categories and/or tags. This way, at least every blog post on the first page of each category/tag is internally linked.
- Manually interlink your blog posts whenever it makes sense.
- Add a "related articles" widget to the bottom of your blog posts. Ideally, one that links to semantically related blog articles. But could also link to random articles.

While all of these things can help, only fixing the pagination issue itself will guarantee that you do not run into problems long-term.